# Extract symbol table from zImage without actual loading

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, arm, elf

I have a Android kernel boot image -- zImage.

How to extract the symbol table from it? Maybe it is in a compressed form.

The system is 32-bit ARM.

I do not have the actual device to load this zImage, and get symbols from /proc/ksyms or /proc/kallsyms or system.map.

I can extract vmlinux from zImage, but still no symbols after objdump.

Comment: _"Maybe it is in a compressed form"_ - er, yes, the "z" in "zImage" signifies that it's Gzipped (but prepended with a self-extractor stub).

Comment: First, you need to unpack your `zImage`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672417/getting-kernel-version-from-the-compressed-kernel-image/37689814#37689814) for details. Then check unpacked `Image` file using `strings` tool (you should be able to find symbols names). Then you can use `objdump` to find symbols table (if you know the offset).

Comment: After decompression, I use strings to find some symbol names. But those symbols seem next to each other, no address is included. Also, how to use objdump to find the symbol table?